# How presence works in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was reading validation from `http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html` . I understand that presence checks whether given attribute is either empty or consists of whitespace. But what I don't understand is that, how to test association is present. They showed two example

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  validates :order, presence: true
end
```

and

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, inverse_of: :order
end
```

I understand the code here but I don't understand how it test association.

Answer (score 1):

`LineItem` has `order_id` and that is what being validated. it is simply checking if that field/column has a value.